# Calling a PHP function from a Javascript Function

Tags: php, javascript

I have a function that is called on body load on a PHP page.

```
<script>
    function testConnection()
    {
        var sDataLoader = readCookie('DataLoader');
        <?php connTest(sDataLoader); ?>     
    }
</script>
```

connTest() is a php function that takes the javascript variable and does something.  Everything about this looks wrong but it works on one of my LAMP servers, and completely blows up(like I would expect) on another.

> Unknown error type: [8] Use of undefined constant sDataLoader- assumed 'sDataloader'

The servers are configured very differently so that's obviously making a huge difference, but I just don't understand why/how it ever works so I can't figure out how to make it work on both servers.

Comment: PHP is executed on the server and the result (the output) is sent to the browser. Then the browser executes the JavaScript.

Comment: If you figure it out, let me know, lol.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're misunderstanding how "everything works" on the LAMP server.

Comment: Ajax is preferred in such situations. Why don't you use it instead?

Comment: I didn't write it, I'm just trying to figure out why it works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time the `<script>` tag is executed on the client, the PHP portion of the code (which was run up on the server) is totally done with.  Fin!  Gone, out of memory, never to be seen or heard from again!

The very concept of calling `connTest` and passing in the Javascript variable `sDataLoader` makes no sense unless you abandon all concepts of linear time.

If you want to execute more code up on the server, you'll need to make a *new* HTTP request and send in the data that is relevant.  There's many ways to do this, including AJAX, IFrames, postbacks, etc.

As to why this "worked" on another server, the obvious answer is it did not.  It's possible there just happened to be a server side variable called `sDataLoader` that did something that could possibly be confused with *working*.

Comment: `sDataLoader` could a constant in the PHP, as the error message implies and the only way I see it doing anything.

Comment: So what would cause this to not throw any errors and "Work" on a server.  Because I have checked thoroughly and $sDataLoader is never defined.

Comment: Without a `$`, check if there isn't any `define('sDataLoader', ...)` there. Unlikely, but it's either that or the function isn't being called at all or your other server is simply ignoring the errors.

Comment: Since `sDataLoader` is just reading the value of a cookie, isn't it possible someone implemented the same cookie-reading code in PHP and used the same variable name?  It's really anyone's guess without having access to *all* the code on the working server.

Comment: It doesn't look like either of those are what's happening.  My best guess is that it somehow accepts the value blindly, proceeds to execute with no real value, and ignores all reason and logic.  I just don't know what in the ini file would configure PHP to do that.

Comment: Perhaps check out your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) - Namely, the setting for *error_reporting*.  There also appears to be some differences in PHP versions.